# Track iPhone Application Usage with PHP and Website

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, statistics

I'm looking for a way to see how often people use my iPhone app within my school. What I'm thinking is having it ping a page when it loads.

I don't know much about web design or PHP, but would it be possible to simply download a PHP page and when that happens, write an entry to a MySQL log?

Or perhaps a better solution? Google Analytics perhaps?

I'd like to keep this nice and simple. Is it possible to just open a HTTP connection?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google analytics can do that just fine. You have an objective-c framework for google analytics on iPhone :

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/

It's very well documented and the support group is very active.

Hope this helps,
Vincent